# How to write to XLSX file on Google Cloud Storage

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

How can I write to an xlsx file on Google Cloud Storage using python? I'm doing this right now but unsure how to format my write() to add in a row. I want to add in a row ['Sally', 'Ja', 15] to my names.xlsx file on cloud storage.

```
import cloudstorage

file = cloudstorage.open('/master/names.xlsx')
file.write(##what goes in here?##)
filehandle.close()
```

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by Travis , you cannot append but re-rewrite the entire object ,example below(assuming text.csv is your existing file) , you can read the file in dataframe , add some data and copy it using gsutil command to GCP bucket. This will overwrite the previous version of text.csv.

```
  import pandas as pd
  data = [['Alex','Feb',10],['Bob','jan',12]]
  df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Name','Month','Age'])
  print df
```

**Output**

```
       Name Month  Age
    0  Alex   Feb   10
    1   Bob   jan   12
```

**Add a row**

```
  row = ['Sally','Oct',15]
  df.loc[len(df)] = row
  print df
```

**output**

```
    Name Month  Age
0   Alex   Feb   10
1    Bob   jan   12
2  Sally   Oct   15
```

**write/copy to GCP Bucket using gsutil**

```
 df.to_csv('text.csv', index = False)
!gsutil cp 'text.csv' 'gs://BucketName/folderName/'
```

**write/copy to GCP Bucket using python**

```
`pip3 install xlsxwriter # install package`
```

**python code**

```
from google.cloud import storage
import pandas as pd

#define configurations
bucket_name = 'my_gcp_bucket'
xlsx_file = 'output.xlsx'

#create dataframe
data = [['Alex','Feb',10],['Bob','jan',12]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Name','Month','Age'])
df.to_excel("output.xlsx")

#Upload to Google cloud storage
client = storage.Client()
bucket = client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
blob = bucket.blob(xlsx_file)
blob.upload_from_filename(xlsx_file)
```

Comment: but I want to my google app engine application to create a xlsx file and store in google storage. this method does not work

Comment: @John updated my post with python code to access GCS bucket.

Comment: @eric chen , please refer to my post

Answer (score 1):

Objects in Google Cloud Storage are immutable, so you cannot append a new row to an existing object.  You would need to rewrite the entire object.

You can get a limited "append" functionality using the [compose API](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/compose), but this only appends bytes to the end of the object and  appending bytes to the end of the object, and I don't believe that can easily achieved for XLSX data.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this with the pandas package is as follow:

`df.to_excel("gs://directory_name/output.xlsx")`

Assuming your code is running in a local development environment, you may need to activate GCP credentials.

1. Install and initialize the gcloud CLI, if you haven't already.
2. Create your credential file:

   `gcloud auth application-default login`

A login screen is displayed. After you log in, your credentials are stored in the local credential file used by ADC. You should be then be allowed to automatically determine credentials.